# Having some doubts about C pointers and memory address

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, pass-by-value

I'm really newbie in C and I have this piece of code about LinkedList in C:

```
struct ListNode* addnode(struct ListNode *head,int val)
{
    struct ListNode* newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newnode->val = val;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (!head) head = newnode;
    else {
        struct ListNode *this = head;
        while(this->next)
            this = this->next;
        this->next = newnode;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct ListNode *head = NULL;

    head = addnode(head,4);
    addnode(head,9);
    addnode(head,1);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: in the main why if I write

```
    addnode(head,4);
    addnode(head,9);
    addnode(head,1);
```

Instead of

```
head = addnode(head,4);
    addnode(head,9);
    addnode(head,1);
```

Doesn't work ? The first one is creating the following linkedlist : 4->9->1, and the second one is creating 3 different Linkedlist heads. But wouldn't it be the same as we are always using the memory address of head ? So the head is always saving his previous node.

Thank you in advance I will appreciate your answers

Comment: Where is the name this used in this line struct ListNode* newnode = malloc(sizeof(*this)); declared?

Comment: Your `*head `parameter is a *copy* of the original head pointer, not the original.  Consequently, it never gets saved to the outside world.  That's why you have to return it.

Comment: Once you reap the head the first time it never changes. because your algorithm always drops items on the tail of the list. But if you never reap it in the first place you never get the initial head node. C arguments are pass by value. `head = ...` means nothing to the caller, so the return result is how any changes to the local `head` within that function are being conveyed to the outside world.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry that line is : struct ListNode* newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

Comment: Please edit the post. don't add information in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the pointer `head` is initialized as a null pointer

```
struct ListNode *head = NULL;
```

This pointer is passed by value to the function `addnode`

```
addnode(head,4);
```

The function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `head` declared in main that is used as an argument expression of the function. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer `head`.

So after the call the pointer `head` will still be a null pointer.

The function returns the modified value of the copy of the pointer

```
struct ListNode* addnode(struct ListNode *head,int val)
{
    //... 
    if (!head) head = newnode;
    //...
    return head;
}
```

To change the original pointer `head` you need to assign the returned value to the pointer `head` like

```
head = addnode(head,4);
```

Now the pointer `head` points to the first node of the list.

All other calls of the function

```
addnode(head,9);
addnode(head,1);
```

append new nodes to the tail of the list. That is these calls do not influence on the value of the pointer that points to the first node of the list. So there is no need to assign the returned value of the function to the pointer `head` though nevertheless you could write

```
head = addnode(head,9);
head = addnode(head,1);
```

To make it more clear consider a very simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f( int x )
{
    x += 1;

    return x;
}

int main( void )
{
    x = 0;

    f( x );

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
}
```

If you will not substitute this statement

```
    f( x );
```

for

```
    x = f( x );
```

then the variable `x` will not be changed in main after calling the function `f` because the function `f` changes a copy of the value of the variable `x`   used as the function argument.